# Typing up a Box class correctly

Tags: typescript

I'm following a [blog post](https://medium.com/@kelleyalex/create-linear-data-flow-with-container-style-types-box-702a3808ad2c) on functional programming using PureScript. There's an example of a Box that looks like this in JavaScript:

```
const Box = x => ({
    map: f => Box(f(x)),
    fold: f => f(x),
    inspect: () => `Box(${x})`
});
```

I would like to type this up using TypeScript to have syntax checking for code like this:

```
const nextCharForNumberString = str => 
  Box(str)
  .map(s => s.trim()) 
  .map(s => new Number(s)) 
  .map(i => i + 1) 
  .map(i => String.fromCharCode(i)) 
  .fold(c => c.toLowerCase());
```

I've attempted to type the Box like this:

```
interface IBox<T> {
    map: <U>(T) => IBox<U>;
    fold: <U>(T) => U;
    inspect: (T) => string;
}

const Box: <T>(x: T) => IBox<T> = x => ({
    map: f => Box(f(x)),
    fold: f => f(x),
    inspect: () => `Box(${x})`
});
```

It stumps me how to correctly type the Box function. In an attempt to simplify the syntax I've tried this too:

```
function Box<T>(x: T): IBox<T> {
    return {
        map: <U>(f): IBox<U> => Box(f(x)),
        fold: <U>(f): U => f(x),
        inspect: () => `Box(${x})`
    };
}
```

None of my attempts work all the way. I would like this to be caught at compile time:

```
const s: IBox<String> = Box(5)
    .map(x => x * x)
    .map(x => x.toString())
    .map(x => x * x)
    .fold(x => x);
```

It seems to me that this is possible with TypeScript. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I think you're pretty close.  Here's a way to type the `Box<T>` interface:

```
interface Box<T> {
  map<U>(f: (t: T) => U): Box<U>;
  fold<U>(f: (t: T) => U): U;
  inspect(): string;
}
```

And here's a way to type the `Box` function which takes an argument of type `T` and produces a `Box<T>` (you can use both `Box` as the type name and the function name since value names and type names exist in different name spaces):

```
const Box = <T>(x: T): Box<T> => ({
  map: f => Box(f(x)),
  fold: f => f(x),
  inspect: () => `Box(${x})`
}); // compiles fine
```

Then you will catch the problem at compile time like you want:

```
const badS = Box(5)
  .map(x => x * x)
  .map(x => x.toString())
  .map(x => x * x) // error, x is a string, you cant multiply it
  .fold(x => x);
```

And be able to fix it:

```
const goodS = Box(5)
.map(x => x * x)
.map(x => x.toString())
.fold(x => x); // goodS is type string

console.log(goodS); "25"
```

Hope that helps; good luck!